# Probability mass function of y

Tags: probability

A single-player game is played by pressing a red button followed by pressing green button. Each time a button is pressed, a number selected at random from the set$ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$ with equal probability, will be displayed on a screen. The ‘score’ of the game is the bigger number out of the two displayed. The game is played repeatedly.
Let the random number variable X donate the score of a randomly selected game.

Let Y be the number of games that need to be played prior to receiving a score greater than 3.

How to find  the probability mass function of Y?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

[Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with success probability $p$ models the number of trials required until a succesful event occur.

It is known that
$$P(Y=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p$$

What you need to do is to compute $p$, the probability that for a particular, the score is greater than $3$. That is $p=P(X \geq 3)$.